# Linq - Select rows which are on lists

Tags: c#, linq, select, entity

I have got table "Actions" which has fields like Player, Game, Type - ale connected with other tables. I have also two Lists in my c# code:

```
    List<Player> playersForStats
    List<Game> gamesForStats
```

Now i want to select a rows from Actions which (field)Players are in list playersForStats and (field)Game are in list gamesForStats. How can I make it using linq? I have to use inner join or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work if your object has proper equals method:

```
var oActions = ..
var oData = oActions.Where(c=> c.Players.TrueForAll(p => playersForStats.Contains(p)) && gamesForStats.Contains(c.Game));
```

Assuming that `c.Players` is `List` And `c.Game` is Field.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume your action list named as actions:

```
actions.Where(x=>playersForStats.Contains(x.Player) && gamesForStats.Contains(x=>x.Game));
```

In fact just need to search if playersForStats and gamesForStats contains related action's player and game.

Comment: @Sparkzi If this works for you mark it as answer by toggling tik in left hand of question to green.

Comment: This worked for me when trying to add more .Where to an iList.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
        List<Game> gamesForStats = new List<Game>();
        List<Player> playersForStats = new List<Player>();

        List<Action> result = (from oAction in actions
                               join game in gamesForStats on oAction.Game equals game.GameName
                               join player in playersForStats on oAction.Player equals player.PlayerName
                               select oAction).ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public string GameName { get; set; }
}

public class Action
{
    public string Player { get; set; }
    public string Game { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solutions works very well but I have one more question.
If I want use this solution:

                List<Action> result = (from oAction in actions
                               join game in gamesForStats on oAction.Game equals game.GameName ......).ToList();

I have to change first line to:

        List<Action> result = (from oAction in actions.asEnumerable()  .....

because actions is my SqlServer table.
It can slow down my program (becuse of conversation and sending data from server)?
Maybe quicker is to use solution with contains() method and make query on SqlServer?

Comment: The fastest solution is to create a View in your DB and directly call it from your server through a webservice for example